# python multiple inheritance output issue

Tags: python

Recently i'm reading a book, it mentioned the mro in multiple inheritance, and give sample code:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "A"
        super(A, self).__init__()

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print "B"
        super(B, self).__init__()

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print "C"
        A.__init__(self)
        B.__init__(self)

C()
```

output:

```
C
A
B
B
```

I wanna know why this happen?

Answer (score 2):

This happens because you're mixing direct constructor calls and calls via `super`. Your class hierarchy should do either one or the other.

More precisely, the MRO for the class `C` is `C, A, B`. Thus, when you call `super(A, self).__init__()` in A's constructor, that calls the constructor for `B`, since `B` succeeds `A` in `C`'s MRO. In other words, it is inside `A`'s constructor that the first `B` is printed.

As an aside, writing out `super(A, self)` is superfluous in Python 3. `super()` is enough; the arguments are [deduced](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3135/) from the context.

Further reading:

- [`super()` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#super)
- [Guide to using `super()`](https://rhettinger.wordpress.com/2011/05/26/super-considered-super/)
- [The C3 method resolution order](https://www.python.org/download/releases/2.3/mro/)

Answer (score 0):

I've converted your code to Python3 (by changing `print` to `print()`) and added some more tracing statements:

```
class A(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("A", type(self).__mro__)
        super(A, self).__init__()
        print("/A")

class B(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print("B", type(self).__mro__)
        super(B, self).__init__()
        print("/B")

class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C")
        A.__init__(self)
        print("ca/b")
        B.__init__(self)
        print("/C")

C()
```

Here's the output:

```
C
A (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
B (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
/B
/A
ca/b
B (<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.A'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
/B
/C
```

Looking at the output, you can see the call to the `C.__init__` method is happening, and printing 'C'. It then calls `A.__init__` directly (which is a mistake- use `super`!).

The `A.__init__` call prints its message, including the `__mro__` attribute. You can see the sequence: C -> A -> B -> Object. This is important, because it means that calls to `super()` from within `A.__init__` are going to refer to class `B`. Also, calls to `super` from inside `C.__init__` would have invoked `A.__init__` automatically, if you let them.

The next method, `B.__init__`, is invoked by the `super` reference inside `A.__init__`, as mentioned. It calls `Object.__init__`, presumably, which prints nothing. ;-)

Both `B.__init__` and `A.__init__` return, we see the midpoint message `ca/b`, and then your direct call to `B.__init__` is made. It prints a message, but again a reference to `super` form `B.__init__` does nothing, because `B` is at the tail end of the MRO.

The `super()` mechanism can deal with all this MRO stuff for you. You shouldn't have to invoke `A.__init__(self)`. Instead, you can just let `super` handle it, inside `C.__init__`, but doing this:

```
class C(A,B):
    def __init__(self):
        print("C")
        super(C, self).__init__()
```

Comment: That's so great!  Thank you